# How to move in Terraria?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I don't know how to move in Terraria, I have tried tapping on the ground and scrolling but it doesn't work? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Given that you tried tapping on the ground, I'm assuming you are playing the Terraria iOS version? - You tagged it with the PC version :)

Answer (score 3):

The movement keys are well described by Cyan. Should you have the mobile version: there are a couple of circles in the bottom left corner. Moving the blue cursor in any direction beyong the most inner circle will cause your character to move in that direction; the speed is depending on how far out you move your cursor. Jumping is the same thing.

It is definitely advisable to stick to PC with this game; touchscreen controls can be quite frustrating if you need to be precise, like in this game.

Answer (score 2):

You can move using the <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> & <kbd>D</kbd> keys.

You can also find a list of all controls [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Game_controls).

Comment: Answer was made before Tag was changed to Mobile version, I'll leave it here for posterity